# jsf p:layoutUnit dynamic update

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to change layoutUnit content dynamic when I change different tab. Now it can change testset when I click on its tab. When I come back to the original tab. All of content in the center disappear. It can not been shown again. Does anyone know about this or how to solve the problem? Thanks.

```xml
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <p:layoutUnit id="layoutunitleft" position="west" size="360"  
            resizable="true" collapsible="true" header="Options" minSize="260">
        <p:accordionPanel id="accordingpanel1" rendered="true" >   
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{mainNavBean.onChange}" update=":mainForm:projectform " />                                          
            <p:tab id="accordingpanel1tab" title="Project">  
            <p:commandLink id="projecttreelink" process="@this" 
                action="#{mainNavBean.setPage('project')}" 
                update=" :mainForm:projectform:scenarioDetailTable :mainForm:projectform:dynaFormGroup" >    
               <h:outputText value="Project" />     
            </p:commandLink>   
            </p:tab>                          
            <p:tab title="Test Set">                                 
               <p:commandLink id="project" process="@this" 
                action="#{mainNavBean.setPage('testset')}" update=":mainForm:projectform" >    
                    <h:outputText value="Test Set" /> 
                </p:commandLink>                                                         
            </p:tab>                          
            <h:column/>                   
        </p:accordionPanel>                 
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <!-- menu end -->
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"  />
        <!-- scenario & step start -->
        <p:layoutUnit id="layoutunitcenter" position="center" >
           <p:layout>
              <h:form id="projectform">                            
                <ui:include src="#{mainNavBean.page}.xhtml" />
              </h:form>
            </p:layout>                          
        </p:layoutUnit>         
    </p:layout> 
</h:form>
```

```java
public class MainNavBean mplements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String page = "project";

    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }
    public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page = page;
    }
}
```

The project.xhtml like this:

```xml
<p:layoutUnit id="layoutsouth" position="south" size="410"  resizable="true" >
<p:panel header="#{tableBean.tabTitle}" id="dynaFormGroup"  
    style="#{tableBean.selectedItemType eq -1? 'display:none':''}" >
....
</p:panel>
<p:layoutUnit id="layoutunitnorthcenter" position="center" resizable="true" layout="block"> 

<p:dataTable id="scenarioDetailTable" value="#{tableBean.scenariosModel}"  var="scenariob" 
             selection="#{tableBean.selectedScenario}" selectionMode="single" rowkey="#{scenariob.id}"  
             rowStyleClass="#{scenariob.itemType ge 1 ? 'old' : null}" rendered="true"  dynamic="true" >
```

Comment: The center p:layoutUnit can be shown when I remove its element p:panel and only keep p:dataTable. But I want to dynamic show the panel and dataTable at the same time.

Comment: The project.xhtml like this. 
:layoutUnit id="layoutsouth" position="south" size="410"  resizable="true" >

                                    <p:panel header="#{tableBean.tabTitle}" id="dynaFormGroup"  style="#{tableBean.selectedItemType eq -1? 'display:none':''}" >
....

Comment: I see you have nested forms. Never ever do such things. First this is invalid HTML, second, there's no way it will work with Jsf-2.